# How to properly fix a bug directly to Master Branch?

Tags: git, gitlab, git-flow

I was recently granted maintainer status in the repository and my remote team just asked to fix a bug directly to Master branch.

Our flow is the following:

1. All Feature branches get merged into a development Branch
2. When time comes we push into a release/testing Branch
3. Once completed we push to our Master Branch

So my first instinct is to create a copy of the latest release branch, fix the bugs and push to Master.
Is this a proper way to fix bugs in Master branch or how should it be handled?

Comment: Since it's your team's workflow, you should ask your team how they'd like you to handle this.

Comment: The master branch might have been protected. In that case, only admin is allowed to push. As @Schwern mentioned, ask your team first.